# How to plot output data of Do-command?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, recursion, numerical-value

The following in a simple numerical solution of the simple harmonic oscillator.

```
  \[Epsilon] = 0.05; x = 0; f = 0; g = 1; i = 0;
    Do[
     f1 = f + \[Epsilon]*g;
     g1 = g - \[Epsilon]*f;
     x1 = x + \[Epsilon]; i1 = i + 1;
     Print[x1, " ", f1, " ", g1];
     x = x1; f = f1; g = g1; i = i1,
     {i, 0, 100}]
```

What I want to do is to plot the outputs. That is to have a graph with f1 on the y-axis and x on the x-axis and another one with g1 on the y-axis and x on the x-axis. I am not sure how to do this. I read in another post here someone suggesting to make a list of all the data and then plot them, but I am not sure I understand how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: None of the data `{f1, g1, x}`-values are saved anywhere. Once you finish the `Do` loop all you're left with are the last two values for each. Are you interested in creating a numerical solver from scratch (i.e,, is that why you're not using `NDSolve`)? Are you tied to using a `Do` loop for this? Or are you interested in the solution itself?

Comment: I tried to use NDSolve, but the solution does not match the theory and the result I should get and I I am trying different ways of getting there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good candidate for `NestList`

```
e = 0.05;
f = 0;
g = 1;
n = 100;

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@Most@NestList[{First@# + e Last@#, Last@# - e First@#} &, {f, g}, n],
 DataRange -> {e, e*n},
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your reply is as good as the one above.

Comment: my problem is the following. I have this  

\[Epsilon] = 0.001; x = 0; f = 0.4; g = 0; i = 0;
Do[
 f1 = f + \[Epsilon]*g;
 g1 = g + \[Epsilon]*(-(2/(x + 0.1))*g + k[f]);
 x1 = x + \[Epsilon]; i1 = i + 1;
 Print[x1, " ", f1, " ", g1];
 x = x1; f = f1; g = g1; i = i1,
 {i, 0, 100000}]

And then I used the command you wrote here to plot it.   

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@
  Most@NestList[{First@# + e Last@#, Last@# - e First@#} &, {f, g}, 
    n], DataRange -> {e, e*n}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}]

The problem. The data seem to converge to a solution, but the plot is oscillatory

Comment: What is k[f] ? I would pose this as a new question showing all steps

Comment: k[f] is a very complicated expression. I will follow your suggestion and pose it as a new question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: here is the link with the new question 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149109/why-the-data-from-do-command-disagree-with-the-plot-i-get-using-them

thank you once again for your time

Answer (score 6):

You could use `AppendTo` to collect the output and then plot. However, I think you have made your recursion unnecessarily complex. You could do something like this:

```
v = {0, 0, 1}
func[eps_] := {#1 + eps,
    {#2, #3}.{1, eps},
    {#3, #2}.{1, -eps}} &;
```

Then achieve your aim with `NestList`, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[dat = NestList[func[eps] @@ # &, v, 100];
 Row[{TableForm[dat[[1 ;; 10]], 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "f", "g"}}],
   ListPlot[{dat[[All, {1, 2}]], dat[[All, {1, 3}]]}, Joined -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, ImageSize -> 200]}], {eps, {0.01, 0.05,
    0.1, 0.2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. Very helpful and seems wonderful

Answer (score 5):

Your system of recursions can be solved exactly using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[ϵ, f, g, x];

{f[ϵ_, n_], g[ϵ_, n_], x[ϵ_, n_]} =
 {f[ϵ, n], g[ϵ, n], x[ϵ, n]} /. RSolve[{
       f[ϵ, n] == 
        f[ϵ, n - 1] + ϵ*g[ϵ, n - 1],
       g[ϵ, n] == 
        g[ϵ, n - 1] - ϵ*f[ϵ, n - 1],
       x[ϵ, n] == x[ϵ, n - 1] + ϵ,
       x[ϵ, 0] == 0, f[ϵ, 0] == 0, g[ϵ, 0] == 1},
      {f[ϵ, n], g[ϵ, n], x[ϵ, n]}, n][[1]] //
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  FullSimplify

(*  {(1 + ϵ^2)^(n/2)*Sin[n*ArcTan[ϵ]], 
   (1 + ϵ^2)^(n/2)*Cos[n*ArcTan[ϵ]], n*ϵ}  *)
```

These expression can be evaluated for all real `{n, ϵ}`

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Join[{Style[#, Bold, 12] & /@ {"n", "x", "f", "g"}}, 
     Table[{n, x[ϵ, n], f[ϵ, n], g[ϵ, n]}, {n, 0, 
       9}]] // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All] &,
   Spacer[10],
   Plot[{f[ϵ, n], g[ϵ, n]}, {n, 0, 130},
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
    FrameLabel -> {Style["n", Bold, 12], None},
    PlotLegends -> {"f[ϵ,n]", "g[ϵ,n]"},
    ImageSize -> 270]}],
 {{ϵ, 0.05}, {0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2}},
 ContentSize -> {600, 250}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and your reply. I think it seems a bit more complicated than the two solutions above, but the plots seem great.