# Why the data from Do-command disagree with the plot I get using them?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerics, numerical-value

This is a question relevant to [How to plot output data of Do-command?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148993/how-to-plot-output-data-of-do-command/149000?noredirect=1#comment400147_149000)

The Differential Equation at hand now is

$\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + \frac{2}{x+0.1} \frac{df}{dx} = k(f)$

I give the code with the definitions for everything in the above. The gist is that the D.E is solved with a simple numerical update procedure.

```
a1 = 10;
a2 = 24;
a3 = 48;
b = 12;
c = 0.1;
A = (a1*a3 - (a2 + b)^2/4)^(1/2);

Subscript[a, B - L][f_] := 10^-2/(1 - b/(2*Pi)*10^-2*Log[f])

Subscript[a, B - L][f]

1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))

Subscript[a, λ][
  f_] := (a2 + b)/(2*a1) Subscript[a, B - L][f] + 
  A/a1*Subscript[a, B - L][f]*
   Tan[A/b*(Log[Subscript[a, B - L][f]] + 3.67407)]

Subscript[a, λ][f]

9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
 Sqrt[39] Tan[
   1/2 Sqrt[13/
    3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
 500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))

Subscript[V, 0][
  f_] := (Pi*Subscript[a, λ][f])/(1 - b/(2*Pi)*10^-2*Log[f])^(
  a2/b)*f^4

Subscript[V, 0][f]

(f^4 π (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
   Sqrt[39] Tan[
     1/2 Sqrt[13/
      3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
   500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2

Subscript[V, HT][f_] := 
 1/2* (- (Pi^2/45)*c^4 + (16*Pi)/12*10^-2/(1 - b/(2*Pi)*10^-2*Log[f])*
     c^2*f^2 - 
    8/(6*Pi)*((4*Pi*10^-2)/(1 - b/12*10^-2*Log[f]))^(3/2)*c*f^3 - 
    8*(10^-2/(
      1 - b/(2*Pi)*10^-2*Log[f]))^2 (-5.41 + 
       Log[(16*Pi*10^-2)/(1 - b/12*10^-2*Log[f])*1/c^2*f^2])*f^4)

Subscript[V, HT][f]

1/2 (-0.0000219325 - 0.00189062 f^3 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) + (
   0.000418879 f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
   f^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
   1250 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2))

Subscript[V, LT][
  f_] := - (c^4 (Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f])^(1/2)/(Pi*c)*f)^((3/2))*
  Exp[-4/c*(Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f])^(1/2)*f]*(1 + 
    15/8*c/(4*(Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f])^(1/2))*f^-1)

Subscript[V, LT][f]


-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(
  1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]) (f Sqrt[1/(
   1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
 3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]))


Subscript[V, mid][
  f_] := - ((-0.3904*c^4 + 
    0.0507*4*(Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f])^(1/2)*f*c^3)/(
  5.219*c^4 - 1.885*4*(Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f])^(1/2)*f*c^3 + 
   16*Pi*Subscript[a, B - L][f]*f^2*c^2))




Subscript[V, mid][f]

-((-0.00003904 + 0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])/(
 0.0005219 - 0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
  0.00502655 f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))))


Subscript[V, eff][f_] := 
 Subscript[V, 0][f] + 
  3*((HeavisideTheta[f] - HeavisideTheta[f - 1.8])*
      Subscript[V, HT][
       f] + (HeavisideTheta[f - 1.8] - HeavisideTheta[f - 4.5])*
      Subscript[V, mid][f] + 
     HeavisideTheta[f - 4.5]*Subscript[V, LT][f])

Subscript[V, eff][f]

3 (-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(
       f Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f]) (-0.00003904 + 
         0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]))/(0.0005219 - 
       0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       0.00502655 f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f] + 
       HeavisideTheta[f]) (-0.0000219325 - 
       0.00189062 f^3 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) + (0.000418879 f^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
       f^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2))) + (
 f^4 π (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2

D[Subscript[V, eff][f], f]

3 (-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      DiracDelta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (-(0.264464/(f^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - (
       0.00252544 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])/f^2) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(
       f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (-7.08982 Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
       0.0677028 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2)) - 
    6.35666*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] Sqrt[
     f Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]] (1 + 0.264464/(
       f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       3 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2))/(
       100 π)) + ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f]) (-0.00003904 + 
         0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]) (-0.00133643 Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
         0.000012762 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2) + (
         0.000096 f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (0.0100531 f)/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))))/(0.0005219 - 
       0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       0.00502655 f^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^2 - ((-DiracDelta[-4.5 + f] + 
       DiracDelta[-1.8 + f]) (-0.00003904 + 
       0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]))/(
    0.0005219 - 0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
     0.00502655 f^2)/(
     1 - (3 Log[f])/(
      50 π))) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f]) (0.0000359454 Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + 
         3.43253*10^-7 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(
          3/2)))/(0.0005219 - 
       0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       0.00502655 f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f] + 
       HeavisideTheta[f]) (-0.00567185 f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(
        3/2) - 0.0000283593 f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(5/2) + (
       8.*10^-6 f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 - (
       0.0000159155 f^2 ((0.502655 f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)^2 + (
          100.531 f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)) (1 - Log[f]/100))/(1 - (
         3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (0.000837758 f)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
       3 f^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       31250 π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) - (
       2 f^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       625 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + 
    1/2 (-DiracDelta[-1.8 + f] + DiracDelta[f]) (-0.0000219325 - 
       0.00189062 f^3 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) + (0.000418879 f^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
       f^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2))) + 
 1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 f^4 π (27/(
    25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
    39 Sec[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])]^2)/(
    50000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
    3 Sqrt[39]
      Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + (
 3 f^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39]
      Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(
 25 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) + (
 4 f^3 π (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2

k[f_] := 3 (-4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
       DiracDelta[-4.5` + f] (f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
      3/2) (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
        f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - 
     4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
       HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
      3/2) (-(0.26446386728801075`/(
         f^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - (
        0.002525443904885155` Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])/
        f^2) - 4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` f Sqrt[
       1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
       HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
      3/2) (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
        f Sqrt[1/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (-7.0898154036220635` Sqrt[1/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
        0.06770275002573074` (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2)) - 
     6.35665812185637`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]) HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + f] Sqrt[
      f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]] (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
        f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
        3 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2))/(
        100 π)) + ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + f] + 
          HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + f]) (-0.00003904000000000002` + 
          0.000035945364096363873` f Sqrt[1/(
           1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]) (-0.0013364302035827594` Sqrt[
           1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
          0.000012761968379850251` (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(
           3/2) + (
          0.00009600000000000002` f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (
          0.01005309649148734` f)/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))))/(0.0005219000000000003` - 
        0.0013364302035827594` f Sqrt[1/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (0.00502654824574367` f^2)/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(
         50 π)))^2 - ((-DiracDelta[-4.5` + f] + 
          DiracDelta[-1.8` + f]) (-0.00003904000000000002` + 
          0.000035945364096363873` f Sqrt[1/(
           1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]))/(0.0005219000000000003` - 
        0.0013364302035827594` f Sqrt[1/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (0.00502654824574367` f^2)/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(
         50 π))) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + f] + 
          HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + f]) (0.000035945364096363873` Sqrt[
           1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + 
          3.4325294263045497`*^-7 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(
           3/2)))/(0.0005219000000000003` - 
        0.0013364302035827594` f Sqrt[1/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (0.00502654824574367` f^2)/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + 
     1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + f] + 
        HeavisideTheta[
         f]) (-0.005671852322897651` f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) - 
        0.000028359261614488252` f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(5/2) + (
        8.000000000000001`*^-6 f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 - (
        0.000015915494309189537` f^2 ((
           0.5026548245743668` f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)^2 + (
           100.53096491487337` f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)) (1 - Log[f]/
           100))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (
        0.0008377580409572782` f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
        3 f^3 (-5.41` + 
           Log[(50.26548245743668` f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
        31250 π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) - (
        2 f^3 (-5.41` + 
           Log[(50.26548245743668` f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
        625 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + 
     1/2 (-DiracDelta[-1.8` + f] + 
        DiracDelta[f]) (-0.00002193245422464303` - 
        0.0018906174409658836` f^3 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) + (
        0.0004188790204786391` f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
        f^4 (-5.41` + 
           Log[(50.26548245743668` f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
        1250 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2))) + 
  1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 f^4 π (27/(
     25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
     39 Sec[1/2 Sqrt[13/
        3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])]^2)/(
     50000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
     3 Sqrt[39]
       Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
        3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
     25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + (
  3 f^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
     Sqrt[39] Tan[
       1/2 Sqrt[13/
        3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
     500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(
  25 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) + (
  4 f^3 π (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
     Sqrt[39] Tan[
       1/2 Sqrt[13/
        3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
     500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2

k[f]

3 (-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      DiracDelta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (-(0.264464/(f^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) - (
       0.00252544 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])/f^2) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] (f Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(
       f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (-7.08982 Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
       0.0677028 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2)) - 
    6.35666*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] Sqrt[
     f Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]] (1 + 0.264464/(
       f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))])) (Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       3 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2))/(
       100 π)) + ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f]) (-0.00003904 + 
         0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]) (-0.00133643 Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] - 
         0.000012762 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(3/2) + (
         0.000096 f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (0.0100531 f)/(
         1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))))/(0.0005219 - 
       0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       0.00502655 f^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^2 - ((-DiracDelta[-4.5 + f] + 
       DiracDelta[-1.8 + f]) (-0.00003904 + 
       0.0000359454 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))]))/(
    0.0005219 - 0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
     0.00502655 f^2)/(
     1 - (3 Log[f])/(
      50 π))) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + f] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f]) (0.0000359454 Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + 
         3.43253*10^-7 (1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))^(
          3/2)))/(0.0005219 - 
       0.00133643 f Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))] + (
       0.00502655 f^2)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + f] + 
       HeavisideTheta[f]) (-0.00567185 f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(
        3/2) - 0.0000283593 f^2 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(5/2) + (
       8.*10^-6 f)/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 - (
       0.0000159155 f^2 ((0.502655 f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)^2 + (
          100.531 f)/(1 - Log[f]/100)) (1 - Log[f]/100))/(1 - (
         3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 + (0.000837758 f)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
       3 f^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       31250 π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) - (
       2 f^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       625 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + 
    1/2 (-DiracDelta[-1.8 + f] + DiracDelta[f]) (-0.0000219325 - 
       0.00189062 f^3 (1/(1 - Log[f]/100))^(3/2) + (0.000418879 f^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)) - (
       f^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 f^2)/(1 - Log[f]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2))) + 
 1/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2 f^4 π (27/(
    25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
    39 Sec[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])]^2)/(
    50000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2) + (
    3 Sqrt[39]
      Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    25000 f π (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2)) + (
 3 f^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(
 25 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^3) + (
 4 f^3 π (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[f])/(50 π))^2

ϵ = 0.001; x = 0; f = 0.4; g = 0; i = 0;
Do[
 f1 = f + ϵ*g;
 g1 = g + ϵ*(-(2/(x + 0.1))*g + k[f]);
 x1 = x + ϵ; i1 = i + 1;
 Print[x1, " ", f1, " ", g1];
 x = x1; f = f1; g = g1; i = i1,
 {i, 0, 100000}
]
```

As was indicated in the beforementioned topic by @eldo I used the following command to plot the data from, hence the solution to the Differential Equation.

```
e = 0.001;
f = 0.4;
g = 0;
n = 100000;

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@Most@NestList[{First@# + e Last@#, Last@# - e First@#} &, {f, g}, n],
 DataRange -> {e, e*n},
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}]
```

The problem is that form the list of data I conclude that the solution seems to converge slowly to zero, as it is desired, but the plot is an oscillation, which is very different. 
[image]

Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, not expressed myself well. I mean I don't understand `ϵ*(-(2/(x + 0.1))*g + k[f]` is not the same though in the plotting procedure `Last@# - e First@#` was unchanged. If what am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I can explain. You say that you don't understand ϵ*(-(2/(x + 0.1))*g + k[f]

If you put the definition of the derivative as a limit in the above and do some trivial algebra, it comes out. I think that the plotting procedure Last@# - e First@# tells it to take the last one minus e times the first one and I don't think it needs to change, unless I have misunderstood

Comment: `f + ϵ*g;` corresponds to `First@# + e Last@#`, now `g + e*(-(2/(x + 0.1))*g + k[f])` does not correspond to `Last@# - e First@#`, it was corresponding to `g - e*f`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I understood the code wrong. So, I'll try to fix this and see what happens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it arised from a misunderstanding and is unlikely to help future readers in its form.